# How to get active tab url from browser?

Tags: python, request-uri

How do I get URL from current tab in browser using python? Using os.environ['REQUEST_URI'] gives an error.
The following is my code :

> > > os.environ['REQUEST_URI']

and the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    os.environ["REQUEST_URI"]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 423, in __getitem__
    return self.data[key.upper()]
KeyError: 'REQUEST_URI'
```

Any other alternatives are also welcome.

Comment: That seems a CGI script. How are you launching it? In a CGI, `os.environ["HTTP_REFERER"]` should point to the URL (if any) that pointed to the script

Comment: Selenium? Do you need to run this code on client side or server side?

Comment: Also, `print(os.environ)` to see what's inside, in case it's not the value you thought you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate to your asked way by "os.environ", you can do it:

- by copy and past by hand
- on other ways than you asked way by python
- by Brotab
- by Selenium
- by xdotool
- by javascript from serversite or by code injection from client side